# Expresso-store: How do I diaplay the quantity of a specific product in the cart?

Tags: expresso-store

Having already added 10 of product *foo* to the cart, I later return to the *foo* product page - how can I display how many *foo's* are already in the cart?

Thanks for any ideas
Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `{qty_in_cart}` variable as seen in the docs https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/product_tag.html#qty_in_cart

Comment: Thanks Justin - I alway look in the doce before coming here - missed it this time.